# Unable to upload file as blob to table using Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper, apex-code

I have a application built using Oracle APEX 20.x.

The issue is need to programmatically upload the `(.pdf,.txt,.png,.jpeg,.jpg)` as a BLOB to table

I heard about the `APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES`.

How to utilize this table to upload my file as BLOB to this following table using `Insert statement`?

I want to achieve this activity on Button click -> dynamic action -> PLSQL coding

Comment: What is "programmatically upload file" ? Do you mean that the user clicks on a "file browse" button, picks a file and then submits the page which will upload the file ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie : I want to achieve by using PLSQL coding not direct method available in APEX like form processing DML

Comment: Yes you keep saying that "PLSQL Coding". You tagged oracle-apex. That is a user interface - users select a file and upload it through the UI. You say that it should be done differently. What does that mean ? Please describe the exact process you have in mind.

Comment: @KoenLostrie : Oracle APEX as by default -> `Automatic Row processing DML`  it is internally handled by APEX it self and insert the image as BLOB in table. But this does not give me much control. I want to write a code on button click -> `Dynamic action -> PLSQL code` so. like `declare .... begin .. end`

Comment: Ok that helps. I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: It is generally bad practice to upload files into BLOB columns. You'll find your database easier to manage if you store your files in a file system, and then just store a string path reference in the database.

Answer (score 0):

here on Stackoverflow, there are great examples about it. but in a nutshell:

```
if :P1_MY_FILE is not null then
 select blob_content, filename, mime_type 
 into l_req_file, l_req_file_name, l_req_mime_type 
 from apex_application_temp_files 
 where name = :P1_MY_FILE ;
end if;
```

should give the idea